# CAST Not Rounding Properly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

If you look below, the syntax is the same but one is pulling variables to calculate while the other is hard coded values. The results are different and I am lost at why this is happening. Does anyone have an explanation?

```
CAST(Amount / Quantity AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) AS [Price1], --36.5087
CAST(584.14 / 16 AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) AS [Price2], --36.5088
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: what are the datatypes used for Amount and Quantity?

Comment: @Lamak . . . These are *decimal* constants, not floating point (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx).

Comment: They are both floats. I am attempting to do the math as floats and then round the result to 4 decimals. I think I am missing something here.

Comment: The constants are implicitly converted to decimals, so the second calc is decimal(5,3) / decimal(2,0).

Comment: Floats have a purpose, but not when dealing with money. Use Money, Decimal, or Numeric data types (or, if you must for some unholy reason, use Int / Bigint with an implied decimal place.) But if you use floats, you will be called in over New Years some year when the End of Year balance sheet shows a $0.01 difference from what is expected...

Answer (score 2):

Simple example to reproduce OP result, MS Sql

```
SELECT
    CAST(CAST(584.14 AS FLOAT) / 16  AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) AS [Price1],
    CAST(584.14 / 16 AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) AS [Price2]
```

Mind datatypes and conversion rules.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that you are using SQL Server (based on the square braces).

The issue that you are seeing is because the types of the literals is not the same as the types of the columns.  The types of the literals is decimal, and there are specific rules for precision and scale when dividing decimal numbers.  "Specific" does not mean simple or intuitive.  But [they](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) are well-documented.

Why does this make a difference?  Well, different representations can result in different results.  The difference will be small, but it might show up in the less significant decimal places.

Comment: select CAST(584.14 / 16 AS DECIMAL(10, 4))
select CAST(584.14 / 16.0 AS DECIMAL(10, 4))
select CAST(CAST(584.14 AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) / CAST(16 AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) AS DECIMAL(10, 4))
all return 36.5088 in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @Alexei . . . No doubt true, but we don't know what the data types of the columns in the question are.

Answer (score 1):

@Drew While doing some research I found this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

which says as we know a Float is **approximate Numerics** vs Decimal which is **Exact Numerics**

on further investigating I came across this link

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx

specifically this para

> Approximate numeric data types do not store the exact values specified
>   for many numbers; they store an extremely close approximation of the
>   value. For many applications, the tiny difference between the
>   specified value and the stored approximation is not noticeable. At
>   times, though, the difference becomes noticeable. Because of the
>   approximate nature of the float and real data types, do not use these
>   data types when exact numeric behavior is required, such as in
>   financial applications, in operations involving rounding, or in
>   equality checks. Instead, use the integer, decimal, money, or
>   smallmoney data types.

so to answer your question if you are planning to do it for financial application use decimal rather than float ;)